# Melhor forma de recuperar a data do sqlite

Tags: android

No sql que é executado no momento de inserir um novo registro o campo data_cad é current_datetime. Qual é a melhor forma de mostrar na activity a data no formato dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm:ss?
Desde já agradeço.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você pode capturar a data em um Date e após com o FormatString converte-la para String e exibir em um Textview.

E para melhorar o processo, acho mais fácil salvar a data no banco em milesegundos, assim para converter em Date é só fazer:

```
new Date(long)

Date data = (data do sql)
SimpleDateFormat dt1 = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm:ss");
String dataFormatada = dt1.format(date));
```